# javascript - onmessage even will not fire using a java server

Tags: java, javascript, websocket

I know this has been asked before, but I have tried all the posts on this site and still no fix so I though I might upload my code and see what im doing wrong.

I am using java for my server and javascript websocket for my client. When I send information from my server to my client nothing happens and also when I send data from client to server nothing is received. Please help?!?!?!

Here is my server code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Server extends JFrame
{
private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
private Scanner fromClient;
private BufferedOutputStream toClient;
private Socket socket;
private static final int TEXT = 1, BINARY = 2, CLOSE = 8, PING = 9, PONG = 10;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Server();
}

public Server()
{
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setTitle("Server");
    setSize(700, 400);
    setLocation(0, 200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    try 
    {
        //create server socket
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8181);
        textArea.append( "Starting Server...\n" );
        textArea.append("Server started at " + new Date() + '\n');

        //Wait for connection
        socket = serverSocket.accept();

        //create input output
        fromClient = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        toClient = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        this.handle_handshake(fromClient);
        textArea.append("\n\nsending text....\n");
        //this.brodcast("pop");
        this.send_message("test");

        int i = 1; 
        while (true)
        {
            String s = fromClient.hasNext() ? fromClient.nextLine() : "";
            textArea.append("Client: " + s + "\n");
            if( i == 0 ) break;
        }

        socket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}

private boolean handle_handshake( Scanner scanner ) 
{
    String line;
    String hash_str = "";
    String key = "";


    int counter = 0;
    while ( scanner.hasNextLine() && (line = scanner.nextLine() ) != null ) 
    {
        String[] tokens = line.split( ": " );


        switch ( tokens[0] ) 
        {

            case "Sec-WebSocket-Key":
                key = tokens[1].trim();

                textArea.append( "SocketKey" );
                hash_str = this.get_return_hash( tokens[1] );
                break;

            case "Sec-WebSocket-Version":
                textArea.append( "WebSock-Ver: " + tokens[1] + "\n" );
                break;

            default:
                textArea.append( tokens[0] + ": " + tokens[tokens.length-1] + "\n" );
                break;
        }

        ++counter;

        if ( counter > 12 ) 
        {
            textArea.append( "Handshake" );
            String msg = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
            msg += "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
            msg += "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
            msg += "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + hash_str + "\r\n";
            msg += "\r\n\r\n";

            try
            {
                toClient.write( msg.getBytes( "UTF-8" ) );
                textArea.append( "Server > Client: " + msg );
                //toClient.flush();
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            textArea.append( "\n\nClosing handshake\n\n" );

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public void brodcast(String mess) throws IOException
{
    byte[] rawData = mess.getBytes();

    int frameCount  = 0;
    byte[] frame = new byte[10];

    frame[0] = TEXT;

    if(rawData.length <= 125){
        frame[1] = (byte) rawData.length;
        frameCount = 2;
    }else if(rawData.length >= 126 && rawData.length <= 65535){
        frame[1] = (byte) 126;
        byte len = (byte) rawData.length;
        frame[2] = (byte)((len >> 8 ) & (byte)255);
        frame[3] = (byte)(len & (byte)255); 
        frameCount = 4;
    }else{
        frame[1] = (byte) 127;
        byte len = (byte) rawData.length;
        frame[2] = (byte)((len >> 56 ) & (byte)255);
        frame[3] = (byte)((len >> 48 ) & (byte)255);
        frame[4] = (byte)((len >> 40 ) & (byte)255);
        frame[5] = (byte)((len >> 32 ) & (byte)255);
        frame[6] = (byte)((len >> 24 ) & (byte)255);
        frame[7] = (byte)((len >> 16 ) & (byte)255);
        frame[8] = (byte)((len >> 8 ) & (byte)255);
        frame[9] = (byte)(len & (byte)255);
        frameCount = 10;
    }

    int bLength = frameCount + rawData.length;

    byte[] reply = new byte[bLength];

    int bLim = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<frameCount;i++){
        reply[bLim] = frame[i];
        bLim++;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<rawData.length;i++){
        reply[bLim] = rawData[i];
        bLim++;
    }


    toClient.write(reply);
    toClient.flush();

    textArea.append("\n\n\nEnd of brodcasting: " + mess + "\n\n\n");
}

private void send_message( String msg ) 
{   
    try 
    {
        textArea.append( "Sending Message: " + msg + "\n" );
        byte[] textBytes = msg.getBytes( "UTF-8" );
        //ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte code = TEXT;

        //opcode
        toClient.write( code );

        //length
        toClient.write( (byte) textBytes.length );

        //data
        toClient.write( textBytes );

        //fin end line
        toClient.write( code );
        toClient.flush();

    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        System.out.printf( "IOE: %s", e.getMessage() ); 
    }

}

private String get_return_hash( String key ) 
{
    textArea.append( "|| " + key + " ||\n"  );
    String protocol_str = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";

    byte[] sha1_bytes = sha1( key + protocol_str );

    String final_hash = new String(Base64.encodeBase64( sha1_bytes ));

    return final_hash;    
}

private byte[] sha1(String input) 
{
    try
    {
        MessageDigest mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        byte[] result = mDigest.digest(input.getBytes());

        return result;
    } 
    catch ( NoSuchAlgorithmException e ) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

And Here is my client code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready( function() 
{
    var ws;
    var host = 'ws://localhost:8181';//'ws://echo.websocket.org';

    if('WebSocket' in window)
    {
        console.log( "Connect" );
        connect(host);
    }

    function connect(host) 
    {
        ws = new WebSocket(host);
        ws.binaryType = 'blob'; //ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';

        ws.onopen = function( evt ) 
        {
            console.log( "Connection opened" );
            console.log( "readyState: " + ws.readyState );
            console.log( evt );
            console.log('protocol: ' + ws.protocol);
            setInterval(test, 5000);
        };

        ws.onerror = function( evt ) 
        {
            console.log( 'Error Code: ' + evt.code );
            console.log( evt );
        };

        ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
        {  
            console.log('reveived data:' + evt.data);
        };

        ws.onclose = function (evt) 
        {
            console.log( "Socket closed" );
            console.log( "Reason: " + evt.reason + " Code: " + evt.code );
            console.log( "Clean Close: " + evt.wasClean );
        };
    };

    function test()
    {
        console.log("waiting...");
        //var data = str2ab("Ping");
        var line = 'waiting...';

        // perform some operations on the ArrayBuffer
        console.log( ws.readyState );
        if (ws.readyState == 1) ws.send(line);

        if (ws.bufferedAmount === 0) 
        {
          console.log('SENT!');
        }
        else 
        {
          console.log('NOT SENT! left over' + ws.bufferedAmount);
        }
    };

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

The biggest (or at least the first) issue that you can resolve is in the handle handshake.

Change:

```
msg += "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + hash_str + "\r\n";
```

to:

```
msg += "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + hash_str;
```

This is causing the handshake to end with three "\r\n".  The client ends the handshake after reading the first two, causing the third to get left in the stream.  This means your last \r\n will get read in as part of whatever data the client tries to read next.  If you try to send the client a message, it will disconnect due to a bad opcode (most likely).